# Using JSON values in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a requirement where I need to have a JSON file & values of which could be used as attribute values in HTML. I am not sure how to begin working on this. Can you please help me?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the `JSON` file?

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve. Your question is not enough to explain your requirements

Comment: view-source:http://kalyani.com/subwaymap/   I am trying to replicate the same. But the values for me would have to come from JSON file. Because JSON can be changed to change the values dynamic. And, We need to include AJAX refresh also. As first step, I am looking at taking the values from JSON

Answer (score 1):

load your json data file via script tag into ur html page ... then use native javascript or some framework (jQuery is my preference) to $(element).attr(name,val)

this could be inside a loop that iterates over your json file where name and val are properties of the item at the current index

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will browse net for examples. Hope I could get it easily

Comment: $(".subway-map").children("li").each(function (index) {
    //alert("hr");
                var ul = $(this);
//alert(ul);
                 $(ul).attr("data-color","#00000");
    //alert(color1);
})
I m trying this. But it doesnt work. can u pls help

Comment: Sorry for the silly question. Its not displaying or updating data-color in this fiddle. Can you pls help

Comment: i'm not sure you understand what you're doing / reading ... data-color attribute IS being updated ... on item 1 and 3 ... please accept my answer or do more research on what you are trying to accomplish